# Парсинг сайта, bs4

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Пишу парсер для сайта, и столкнулся с проблемой, что внутри тега `a` есть ещё тег `span` и при парсинге использовав
`get_text(strip=True)`
получаю этот текст:
`Сдам 2х-квартиру, Салтовка, трц Украина, м. Ак. Барабашова.(№ 111386487)`

Html код:

```
<div class="title">    
  <h2>
    <a href="/kvartiry_komnaty_arenda/ann-1386487-0.html">Сдам 2х-квартиру, Салтовка, трц Украина, м. Ак. Барабашова.&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <span>(№ 111386487)</span>
    </a>
  </h2>  
</div>
```

Мне нужны данные которые находятся возле `href` ссылки, а именно:

`Сдам 2х-квартиру, Салтовка, трц Украина, м. Ак. Барабашова.&nbsp;&nbsp;`

Возможно ли с помощью bs4 получить только эти данные? P. s. прошу заметить, что сайт постоянно обновляет информацию

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
html = """
<div class="title">    
  <h2>
    <a href="/kvartiry_komnaty_arenda/ann-1386487-0.html">Сдам 2х-квартиру, Салтовка, трц Украина, м. Ак. Барабашова.&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <span>(№ 111386487)</span>
    </a>
  </h2>  
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
r = soup.find('a').contents[0]
print(r)
```

,[image: введите сюда описание изображения]